# ngBootstrap or Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have two questions:

First, does `ngBootstrap` support `Angular 4`? I can see examples on Google where people are using `Angular 4` with `ngBootstrap` but at the official site they have mentioned that it has dependencies on `Angular 5` and higher?

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Screenshot:

[image]

Second question, I am confused between which one to use out of `ngBootstrap` or `Bootstrap 4` for my project which requires a lot of custom styling of controls. Previously I have worked with `Bootstrap 3` and I know how to customize it using `custom_variables` and `Bootstrap 4` works in the same fashion but I can't find how `ngBootstrap` works for customization. One thing I know about that is by using `ng-deep` or `/deep/` or `>>>` but how to give style to the controls in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does ngBootstrap support Angular 4?

Not anymore, the last version that support Angular 4 was ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.6

> Which one to use out of ngBootstrap or Bootstrap 4?

ng-bootstrap can't work without Bootstrap 4 and the customisation of SASS variables is inside Bootstrap 4.

ng-bootstrap is just a replacement of the Javascript of Bootstrap in order to implement it in Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am using Angular 4 in my project so is it possible to work with `ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.6` in that?

Comment: Yes it will work, but you will not have the latest improvements and bug fixes, and you will have to keep the current version of Bootstrap. It would be simpler if you use Angular 5.